# How to change the Internet Explorer Font using C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, registry

I have the following code

```
  string regStrKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\International\\Scripts\\3";
        bool bolWritable = true;
        string strName = "IEPropFontName";
        object oValue = fontName;
        RegistryKey oKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(regStrKey, bolWritable);
        var obj = oKey.GetValue(strName);            
        oKey.SetValue(strName, oValue);
        oKey.Close();
```

This is changing the location correctly, but when I check the IE setting I see that the font for webpages is not selected anymore? Should I be doing something else? Is the "regStrKey" correct?

**NOTE**:

just found this page
[IE10 registry keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479870.aspx)
so as far as I can see the keys are correct. But why dose IE doesn't show the new font in the webpage font in

internet options > fonts(bottom of the first tab) > font type for web pages (left textlist)

**Update**

[Hans passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) was 100% correct. I had to remove the code and put it in another project to see the misspelling. The positive side was that I read a lot :-).

cheers,
es

Comment: Well, what is the value of `fontName`?  The most obvious reason is that the font is not in the list.

Comment: The font is not in the standard windows set and I had installed it, but it was in the list when I run this code and I could manually select it.